# What is the ratio between particles with an uncollapsed wavefunction and particles with a collapsed wavefunction?

Tags: wavefunction, wavefunction-collapse

I wonder what the ratio between particles with an uncollapsed wavefunction and particles with a collapsed wavefunction is.

On earth, in a galaxy or in the universe.

Or is better to say:
What is the ratio between recohered and decohered wave function? On earth, in a galaxy or in the universe.

Comment: What does "collapsed" mean?  Does it mean "in some eigenstate of some observable"?.  If so, then all wave functions are collapsed.   Or do you want to fix a particilar observable, in which case the answer is surely that essentially no wave function is collapsed?

Comment: The wave function collapse meme is basically useless in physics. It's an obfuscation of what is actually happening. A quantum is an irreversible energy transfer. So if you are looking at an atom in a ground state, then you know that it must have given off all of its energy to the vacuum in form of photons. That, however, means that the vacuum is now in an excited state. In the collapse language that means that "the atom is collapsed and the vacuum is now "un-collapsed"". That is a completely useless statement.

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to answer your question because being "collapsed" or "uncollapsed" is not an absolute property of the wavefunction - it depends on the observer.

Take Schrodinger's cat as an example. To an observer inside the box, the cat's wavefunction has collapsed - its state is either alive or dead. But to an observer outside of the box, isolated from the cat, its wavefunction has not collapsed - it is in a superposition of "alive" and "dead" states.

So your question is like asking "how many things in the universe are travelling faster than I am".

Comment: Thank you

How large should the box be with respect to the particle dimensions  to be an “outside the box observer”? Is it depending on traveling speed difference?

Comment: Schroedinger's cat teaches the false ontology in the first place. A closed system does not allow for measurement except by time scale separation and open systems make measurements automatically because the energy is lost to infinity. It basically just obfuscates the actual physics.